# How do I get a user's facebook username (and other user info) when logged Firebase?

Tags: swift, facebook, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building an iOS app in Xcode. I log users in with Facebook via Firebase and each new user is created within the firebase realtime database accordingly. When signing in, users give me access to their public profile information. How can I access this information and add it to the list of properties stored within each user in the database?

Eg, when a user logs in, a new user is created in the database (already working) with their facebook username (eg facebook.com/xxxx), full name, email etc all stored as separate values within the user (no idea how to do this even after reading the docs).

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: There is no way to get username. You can only get firstname and lastname

Comment: How could I get their username then? Maybe just ask users to input it manually when logging in and store it in the database? @WizKid

Comment: what for? you can identify returning users with their app scoped id. there is no need to store the username, and you could only get it manually from the user anyway.

Comment: Yeah thanks I guess I will just ask them to provide to via a form. I just assumed that I could access the user profile as describes in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKProfile/ I just wanted their facebook username to transition from my app to a specific facebook user's messenger page. @luschn

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get basic profile info including profile URL from [`AdditionalUserInfo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/AdditionalUserInfo) on sign-in success.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at Facebook developer help on the subject.

This is how you can connect multiple apps together:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/connecting-accounts